# PHP - I can't make assoc array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have this code:

menu.php

```
<?php
$menu = [
    [
        "id"->"home",
        "name"->"Home page",
        "url"->"/index.php"
    ]
}; ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'menu.php';
$menubar = [
    "menu" -> $menu,
    "current" -> "home" // this line
]; ?>
<!-- and some html -->
```

And, of course, it isn't working.

Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '"home"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11`

How to repair this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use "aaa"=>"bbb" instead of "aaa"->"bbb" with =

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it is that simple ;)